# Magento2 confirm widget: Continue with url

Tags: magento2, backend, jquery, uicomponent, widget

I have an extension with a backend view where I have a button which routes to another url. When the user clicks the button I want to show a pop up which asks him a second time if he/she really wants to continue. I have the following code in my template:

```
<button class="action-third" type="submit" title="Reset" id="reset-all" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $block->getUrl('some/url/reset') ?>')">
    <span>Reset all</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ], function($, confirmation) {
        $('#reset-all').on('click', 'button.action-third', function(event){
            confirmation({
                title: 'Reset...',
                content: 'Do you really want to reset?',
                actions: {
                    confirm: function(){},
                    cancel: function(){},
                    always: function(){}
                }
            });
        })
    });
    // ]]></script>
</div>
```

But that does not work. Here are my two questions:

- What do I have to do so that the pop up shows up?
- What should I insert in the `confirm()` and `cancel()` function so that if the user clicks OK, he gets to the route the button links to, otherwise not.

Comment: how did you done this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in adminhtml area then you can use `confirmSetLocation()` function in javascript like this:

```
var url = '<?php echo $block->getUrl('some/url/reset') ?>';
$('#reset-all').on('click', 'button.action-third', function(event){
    confirmSetLocation('Do you really want to reset?', url);
});
```